# Listar Directorio y Ficheros .bat

Tags: batch

Hola Estoy tratando de listar un directorio con su contenido en código batch y guardarlo en un txt que tenga como nombre la fecha.txt, lo que me hace falta es algo como un árbol geneológico
he probado con:

`dir /s /b > Listar.txt    dir /s > Listar.txt`

y no es lo que me hace falta, dejo una imagen para que vean como me haría falta que quedara espero que me puedan ayudar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. También es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Aqui te dejo una guía de cómo deberían ser los ejemplos: [mínimos, completos y verificables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Bienvenido Tony, revisa los enlaces que te comparte Julio son importantes para cuando realices preguntas en el sitio. En cuanto a tu pregunta simplemente define la ruta del directorio a analizar despues de "dir", saludos.

Comment: probaste `tree Carpeta1`? onda: `tree /A Carpeta1 > listado.txt` (el /a usa guiones)

Comment: si tambien pero me da la información de los archivos que no me hace falta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deseas se puede lograr con el comando [**tree**](http://www.bat-to-exe.com/batchcommands/tree.html).

> [**tree**](http://www.bat-to-exe.com/batchcommands/tree.html) :  Permite al usuario ver una lista de archivos y carpetas
> en una lista fácil de leer.

usando las siguientes opciones:

> **/f**    : Despliega los nombres de archivo en cada directorio
>
> **/a**    : caracteres de extensión utilizados para vincular líneas, en lugar de caracteres gráficos. / a se usa con páginas de códigos que no admiten caracteres gráficos y para enviar resultados a impresoras que no interpretan correctamente los caracteres gráficos.

Esta sería la llamada:

```
tree <Directorio> /f /a > Listar.txt
```

Mas información: [**comando tree**](https://www.computerhope.com/treehlp.htm)  (inglés)

---

Este es un ejemplo de como se guardaría en tu archivo:

```
Volume serial number is 1A4C-12AB
C:\myData\
|   art_dum.png
|   cockpit.png
|         
|   \---particles
|       |   default.html
|       |   
|       +---css
|       |       doc.txt
|       |       site.min.css
|       |       
|       +---fonts
|       |   +---Material
|       |   |       MaterialIcons-Regular.eot
|       |   |       MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf
|       |   |       MaterialIcons-Regular.woff
|       |   |       MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2
|       |   |       
|       |   +---NimbusMono
|       |   |       nimbusmono-regular-webfont.ttf
|       |   |       nimbusmono-regular-webfont.woff
|       |   |       nimbusmono-regular-webfont.woff2
|       |   |       
|       |   \---roboto
|       |           Roboto-Bold.woff
|       |           Roboto-Bold.woff2
|       |           Roboto-Light.woff
|       |           Roboto-Light.woff2
|       |           Roboto-Medium.woff
|       |           Roboto-Medium.woff2
|       |           Roboto-Regular.woff
|       |           Roboto-Regular.woff2
|       |           
|       \---js
|               site.min.js
|               |                           
\---tototita
        archivo.bat
```

Comment: si obtengo la lista completa del directorio pero primero me pone el primer directorio y despues más debajo el subdirectorio hasta llegar a los archivos y lo que me hace falta es algo como un árbol geneológico

Comment: Tony estas son de las cosas que debes especificar en tu pregunta.

Comment: @Tony actualicé mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

```
set MIFECHA=%DATE:/=-%
set MI_DIRECTORIO_BASE=D:\TEMP
tree %MI_DIRECTORIO_BASE% /F /A >%MIFECHA%.txt
```

Comment: Probe con `tree /F /A > listado.txt` y me salio mas o menos como me hace falta

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta para añadir los parámetros /F (muestra los ficheros contenidos en la carpeta) y /A (Usa ASCII en la salida, será mejor para redirigirlo a un fichero) Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como 'aceptada', gracias

Comment: Y como se puede poner para que el nombre del fichero sea la fecha en formato dia-mes-año.txt

Comment: No puedes hacerlo con tree. Para algo tan específico, deberías programarlo tú. Deberás recorrer los directorios de manera recursiva (pasando el nivel) e ir pintando el árbol acorde al nivel al que estás. Y en lugar de escribir el nombre de fichero, imprimes la fecha.

Comment: No ,no lo que quiero es tree /F /A > dia-mes-año.txt

Comment: Ah vale! He editado la respuesta con lo que necesitas